# Setting Cartthrob Price Modifiers Across Many/All Products

Tags: cartthrob

We're working on a project where we need to capture some text information for each item in the cart. We've set this up using the cartthrob_price_modifiers_configurator field type on the appropriate field group.

Is there a way to create these particular modifiers globally without doing so for each of the >800 Entries?

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Greg

Answer (score 1):

I think the way to do this is by hard coding the modifiers and adding them to your product pages via the `item_options` tag. I would most likely go with an include template that could be dropped into the product add to cart template to do this quickly. Furthermore, by adding some if/else logic to the embed, you can setup item_options per category or item type.

For reference, [here is the CT manual page](https://www.cartthrob.com/docs/tutorials/hard_coding_price_modifiers_and_product_options/index.html) that discusses hard coding the modifiers.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a useful addon for creating "Global Item Options".
See https://www.cartthrob.com/site/product_detail/global-item-options